# Odd warning about iconv() function

Tags: php, iconv

I am getting the following warning in mylog file:

```
PHP Warning:  iconv(): Charset parameter exceeds the maximum allowed length of 64 characters in /home/jnj/PlancakeEmailParser.php on line 283
```

The block in question (part of the `getBody()` function):

```
if (!$detectedContentType)
    {
        // if here, we missed the text/plain content-type (probably it was
        // in the header), thus we assume the whole body is what we are after
        $body = implode("\n", $this->rawBodyLines);
    }

    // removing trailing new lines
    $body = preg_replace('/((\r?\n)*)$/', '', $body);

    if ($contentTransferEncoding == 'base64')
        $body = base64_decode($body);
    else if ($contentTransferEncoding == 'quoted-printable')
        $body = quoted_printable_decode($body);        

    if($charset != 'UTF-8') {
        // FORMAT=FLOWED, despite being popular in emails, it is not
        // supported by iconv
        $charset = str_replace("FORMAT=FLOWED", "", $charset);

        $bodyCopy = $body; 
        $body = iconv($charset, 'UTF-8//TRANSLIT', $body);

        if ($body === FALSE) { // iconv returns FALSE on failure
            $body = utf8_encode($bodyCopy);
        }
    }

    return $body;
}
```

I am using `PlancakeEmailParser.php` to parse emails. I have Googled the error and nothing pops out at me. Anyone have any ideas of how or if I need to deal with this?

Comment: please post the code block in question.

Comment: @Dan Added code as requested.

Comment: So what does `$charset` actually contain the moment you pass it to `iconv`?

Comment: My bet is, your input charset is garbage. Try `var_dump`ing it and see what it actually contains.

Comment: @Dan good catch. The charset starts with 3DUTF-8" /></HEAD><BODY BG  Obviously wrong. This is the definition in the original email:  charset=3DUTF-8"   Do I have to covert first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you say you are use PlancakeEmailParser.php class.

just search to line :-

```
$bodyCopy = $body;
```

and change to :-

```
$bodyCopy = quoted_printable_decode($body);
```